# Syncing messages, calendar via iCloud between restored iPhone to one migrated using Move to iOS

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, android, messages-in-icloud

For many years I used iPhone, but then tried to use Android. I'm now back on an iPhone. On the new iPhone I restored it with the last backup from my old iPhone. All is good.

I used "Move to iOS" to migrate my mom's Android to iPhone and that worked very well.

I thought that - after I had restored my old backup to the new iPhone - that I could use "Move to iOS" to transfer data to the new iPhone. Apparently you can't without wiping it.

My question is: Could I take my old iPhone which is now obsolete and use "Move to iOS" to migrate from the Android phone to that. Then after it has migrated, sign in with my Apple ID. Would it then sync messages and calendar to iCloud and now be available on both iPhones?

I *could* try it out, but I would be rather sad if something got deleted. I would like to know if anyone had experience doing this or something similar?

Comment: I need slightly more information.  If you are talking about apps I’m not aware of an option.  But everything else should be syncable by Gmail minus messages.

Comment: I don't want Google products on the new phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is perfectly safe and will work as long as you look carefully select merge and not override. I cannot simulate such a test now, and therefore there is most likely no risk at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In "Move to iOS" there is no merge option.

Comment: @ineedhelp What I mean is that when enabling iCloud sync on your newly transferred old phone, when you enable iCloud sync, it'll probably ask you if you want to merge existing (transferred) content.

Comment: I finally got it to work. The sync did not work on the version of phones and the "Move to iOS" tools. I updated Android, iPhone and "Move to iOS" to the latest versions and then it worked. Thank you for your help.